# how to block ip addresses using the whois command

Tags: linux, networking, domain, whois

I am trying to block public ip addresses/ranges of specific organizations in my firewall.

To accomplish the purpose, I need to find out the actual list of netblocks/IP addresses they own.

For facebook, I've used the following command and it worked as expected.

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | awk '/^route:/ {print $2;}' \
| sort | uniq
```

Would you advise me how to write a chain of commands to find public ip addresses/routes using as basis the **whois** command?

Comment: Please dedicate some time to write  better posts. In British English, using "I want" all the time can also be construed as rude. Cheers.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sure